# Why does glBindBuffer has a unsigned int as its second parameter?

Tags: c++, opengl

As far as I know , I need to firstly generate a buffer's name by calling glGenBuffers , which allocates some RAMs to a specific object(array) named by developer manually . That's why I need to write codes in the form of 'glGenBuffers(int, actually address)'. So whereby , if I want to give some RAMs a specific usage , I need to call glBindBuffer , attributing the target 'usage' to the first parameter , the RAMs to the second parameter .
That's the problem . Why should I attribute an int value to this second parameter?
Isn't a specific address like &xxx ?
Just like what I have done in glGenBuffers : confirm an area where the buffer datas should be stored.
Does glBindBuffer locate the certain address in its body automatically, but doesn't require developers to type in a pointer ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood the parameters of `glGenBuffers` correctly. The second parameter is a pointer to an uint array into which the generated buffer **id** s are written. This are the ids you also have to pass to `glBindBuffer`. Neither of this function allocates memory for you.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the functions work. Lets say you want to create and bind one single buffer, then you first create the buffer `GLuint buffer; glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);` Then you need to bind this buffer to the target: `glBindBuffer(some_target, buffer);` The `buffer` variable is an *identifier*, whose value identify a single buffer in the OpenGL memory.

Comment: See [`glGenBuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml): _buffers_
Specifies an array in which the generated buffer object names are stored.

Comment: @BDL I had figured it a little out . When I set the first param to 1, it is surely me who decide the RAM distribution , but I found that if I set it to 2, then program would automatically allocate the next address for the next index . glGB(2,&x) = &x for 1 and &x+1 for 2( if there is no other glGBs before)

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yes . After looking up the official guide book , I realized that al l buffers are distinguished by different numbers

Comment: @DeLoris: The pointer has nothing to do with the data in the buffer. The memory where you point to has to have size of `number_of_buffers * sizeof(unsigned int)`. There is also no guarantee that you will get consecutive numbers returned. OpenGL is free to give you any id's it likes, as long as they are not already in use. It might be a language thing, but "allocate" means something very specific in C++: Reserving RAM memory for your application. Neither glGenBuffers nor glBindBuffers will allocate any memory.

Answer (score 0):

`glGenBuffers` chooses a bunch of ID numbers for buffers, then stores the ID numbers into your variable. `glBindBuffers` selects one of the buffers based on its ID number. You don't get to see the addresses of any buffers.

Comment: So it is a unsigned int (and I can know it is only 4 bytes ) where the specific ID of a buffer was stored ? And the specific memories for this buffer are allocated after binding ?

Comment: @DeLoris: The memory for the buffer is allocated when you call `glBufferData`.

Comment: @BDL thx. Now it makes more sense